# num1 >= 0x80 - What is 0x80?

Tags: c#

i see this in some code? Checks an int is greater then 0x80. What is 0x80? Is not an int.

Thanks

Comment: "Is not an int."?  Why do you say that?  What does the C# language manual say?  Hint. Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Ofter used in `varint` serialization, to save space

Answer (score 39):

It *is* an integer literal - it's the hex number 80, which is decimal 128. The "0x" prefix indicates it being in hex.

For more details, look at the section 2.4.4.2 of the C# language specification: ["Integer literals"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

That is the hexadecimal literal for 128.  It actually is an int.  Any literal that starts with `0x` is a hexadecimal literal.

Answer (score 3):

It's a [hexadecimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664812.aspx) number.

Comment: Glad to be of service. I saw the same mistake in two of the answers and had to do something about it. Also, I want that "Copy Editor" gold badge ;)

Answer (score 1):

`0x...` is hexadecimal notation of an integer

```
0x80 = 128
```

Answer (score 1):

The prefix 0x means it's hexadecimal, 0x80 means 128 in decimal. Likewise 128 would mean 0x80 in hex. So this is perfectly valid:

```
int x = 0x80;
```

Answer (score 0):

0x80 is an integer (`int`) or character (`char`) using [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) notation of Unix shells, AT&T assembly, and C programming language and its syntactic descendants. It is the same than 128 in decimal, or 0b10000000 in binary.

If representing an `int`, it means 128. `num1 >= 0x80` checks that the number is greater or equal to 128.

If representing a `char`, it is the first character in the Extended ASCII set and thus depends on the character set (charset). For example in the [Windows-1252 charset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), it represents €. `char1 >= 0x80` checks that the character is not a base ASCII character.